# ¿Cuál es el formato para Test Unitario en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, test, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy intentando hacer test unitario y este es el formato de salida de mi api:

```
{
  "data": {
    "company": {
      "idCompany": 1,
      "name": "My Company",
      "noUsers": 1,
      "users": [
        {
          "idUser": 1,
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Mi test unitario esta usando:

```
$response
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJsonStructure($expected);
```

¿Cuál es el formato para que la variable `$expected` coincida con mi formato json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También podría utilizar `assertJsonStructure` para verificar la estructura del `JSON` devuelto por su petición de la siguiente forma.

```
//Ruta GET que retorna el JSON
$response = $this->json('GET', '/nombreruta');
$response->assertStatus(200)
 //validamos que tenga la misma estructura la respuesta obtenida
->assertJsonStructure([
   'data' => [
     'company' =>['idCompany','name','noUsers','users']
   ]
]);
```

Bastará con que una clave no coincida para que arroje el fallo del test.

Answer (score 0):

Usa seeJsonStructure() para verificar la estructura de tu json y pasalos de esta forma:

```
$this->get('/company/1')
         ->seeJsonStructure([
             'data' => [
                'company' => [
                     'idCompany', 
                     'name', 
                     //las demas llaves
                ],
             ],
         ]);
```